# Issues in with line end when writing multiple files into one file with C#

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

I'm trying to write 4 sets of 15 txt files into 4 large txt files in order to make it easier to import into another app.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AggregateMultipleFiles
{
    class AggMultiFilestoOneFile
    {/*This program can reduce multiple input files and grouping results into one file for easier app loading.*/
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("G:/user/data/yr2009/fy09_filtered.txt");  
        int linelen =495; 
        char[] buf = new char[linelen];
        int line_num = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        {
                TextReader reader = File.OpenText("G:/user/data/yr2009/fy09_filtered"+i+".txt"); 
            while (true)
            {
                int nin = reader.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (nin == 0 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File ended");
                    break;
                }
                writer.Write(new String(buf));

                line_num++;
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
        writer.Close();

    }
  }
}
```

My problem is somewhere in calling the end of the file. It doesn't finishing writing the last line of a file, and then, proceeds to start writing the first line of the next file half way through the middle of the last line of the previous file.

This is throwing off all of my columns and data in the app it imports into.

Someone suggested that perhaps I need to pad the end of each line of each of the 15 files with carriage and line return, \r\n.

1. Why doesn't what I have work?
2. Would padding work instead? How would I write that?

Thank you!

Comment: You know you can append text files together with the command prompt "copy" command, right?

Comment: No, but I'm certainly open to trying it! Each file contains approximately 1 million rows of info, and I'm afraid of losing any of it. Would that be safe?

Comment: It's been around since the DOS days (the 80s). I'm pretty sure they've worked most of the major glitches out.

Comment: It did not append into fy09_filtered1.txt as I was expecting it too. 
I did the first 4 as a test : 
COPY G:/user/data/yr2009/fy09_filtered1.txt+fy09_filtered2.txt+fy09_filtered3.txt+fy09_filtered4.txt

Answer (score 4):

I strongly suspect this is the problem:

```
writer.Write(new String(buf));
```

You're always creating a string from *all* of `buf`, rather than just the first `nin` characters. If any of your files are short, you may end up with "null" Unicode characters (i.e. U+0000) which may be seen as string terminators in some apps.

There's no need even to create a string - just use:

```
writer.Write(buf, 0, nin);
```

(I would also strongly suggest using `using` statements instead of manually calling `Close`, by the way.)

It's also worth noting that there's *nothing* to guarantee that you're really reading a line at a time. You might as well increase your buffer size to something like 32K in order to read the files in potentially fewer chunks.

Additionally, if the files are small enough, you could read each one into memory completely, which would make your code simpler:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText("G:/user/data/yr2009/fy09_filtered.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        string inputName = "G:/user/data/yr2009/fy09_filtered" + i + ".txt";
        writer.Write(File.ReadAllText(inputName));
    }
}
```